# Form submit button not working php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, submit, form-submit

i'm trying to update data from mysql 
this is the form and it's working fine 
code:

```
$sb2e = mysql_query("select * from blocks where b_id ='$b_id' ");
$rbe  = mysql_fetch_object($sb2e);
if ($_REQUEST['edit'] == 'block')
{
echo ("<form action='?cpages=blocks' method='post'>
<table align='center' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td width='20%'>اسم المربع الجانبي</td>
<td width='80%'><input type='text' name='b_name' id='inputwrap' value='
".$rbe- >b_name."'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='20%'>ترتيب المربع الجانبي</td>
<td width='80%'><input type='text' name='b_order' id='inputwrap' value='
".$rbe->b_order."'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='20%'>مكان المربع الجانبي</td>
<td width='80%'> ");
if ($rbe->b_dir == 1)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ") ;
}
else if ($rbe->b_dir == 2)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ");
}
else if ($rbe->b_dir == 3)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ");
}
else if ($rbe->b_dir == 4)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ");
}


echo ("
<tr>
<td width='20%'>محتوى المربع الجانبي</td>
<td width='80%'><textarea name='b_content' id='inputwrap' rows='5' cols='40'>
".$rbe-  >b_content."</textarea> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='20%'>حالة المربع الجانبي</td>
<td width='80%'>
"); if ($rbe->b_active == 1) {
  echo ("
<select name='b_active' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='1'>مفعل</option>
<option value='2'>غير مفعل</option>
</td>
</tr> ");} else if ($rbe->b_active == 2)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_active' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='2'>غير مفعل</option>
<option value='1'>مفعل</option>
</td>
</tr> ");
}   echo ("
<tr>
<td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='تحديث' class='button' /></td>
</tr></table>
<input type='hidden' name='edit' value='blocks' />
<input type='hidden' name='b_id' value='".$rbe->b_id."' />
</form> ");
}
```

and this is the update query 
 code

```
 if (isset($_POST['edit']) and $_POST['edit'] == 'blocks')

 {
 $updateblocks = mysql_query("update blocks 
 set  b_dir='$b_dir'
 ,b_order='$b_order'
 ,b_name='$b_name'
 ,b_content='$b_content',b_active='$b_active' where b_id='$b_id'

 ") or die (mysql_error());
 if ($updateblocks)
 {
  echo "done";
 }
 }
```

the problem is when i press update "it's the word "تحديث" in the code"
nothing happens without any error report 

 post values

```
$b_dir = strip_tags($_POST['b_dir']);
 $b_order = $_POST['b_order'];
 $b_name = strip_tags($_POST['b_name']);
 $b_content = addslashes($_POST['b_content']);
 $b_active = $_POST['b_active'];
 $b_id = intval($_GET['id']) ;
```

Comment: Note that this method (mysql_) is now deprecated. See PDO/mysqli

Answer (score 0):

First thing i think you should use something like this
first generate function called `selected` as example

```
function selected(a , b){
    if( a == b ) {
      return ' selected="selected" ' ;
    }
}
```

In this Part `مكان المربع الجانبي`  In english it mean " Block Position "

Instead of using  this

```
if ($rbe->b_dir == 1)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ") ;
}
else if ($rbe->b_dir == 2)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ");
}
else if ($rbe->b_dir == 3)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ");
}
else if ($rbe->b_dir == 4)
{
  echo ("
<select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
<option value='4'>يسار</option>
<option value='2'>اعلى المنتصف</option>
<option value='1'>يمين</option>
<option value='3'>اسفل المنتصف</option>
</select></td>
</tr> ");
}
```

You should Use Our Selected Function

```
echo "
    <select name='b_dir' id='inputwrap'>
    <option value='4' ".selected(  4 , $rbe->b_dir )." >يسار</option>
    <option value='2' ".selected(  2 , $rbe->b_dir ).">اعلى المنتصف</option>
    <option value='1' ".selected(  1 , $rbe->b_dir )." >يمين</option>
    <option value='3' ".selected(  3 , $rbe->b_dir )." >اسفل المنتصف</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr> ";
```

and for your problem

Please print the `$_POST` after submit  and check all vales First

Best regards
`Sec.php`

Comment: thanks ^^ for help <br> after putting echo $_POST it's giving me the word "array"?

Comment: No brother , you should use print_r( $_POST ) ;  to print the post array , echo will not work here

Comment: it's printing 1 in echo or print_r

Comment: ah sorry my bad :(  Array ( [b_name] => يمينs [b_order] => 1 [b_dir] => 1 [b_content] => يي [b_active] => 2 [edit] => blocks [b_id] => 15 ) 1
array is true but it's not inserted into the db

Comment: <input type='hidden' name='edit' value='blocks' />
um.. this it?